# ng-include не работает - день потерян

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.data = {};
        $scope.term = ['question1','question2','question3'];
        $scope.add = function(){
            if($scope.data.mode == 'question1')
                return 'answer.html';
            else if($scope.data.mode == 'question2')
                return 'question.html';
            else if($scope.data.mode == 'question3')
                return 'price.html';
        };
        $scope.list = {};
        $scope.result = function(){
            if($scope.list.mode == 'yes')                   
                return 'Ответ верный';
            else if($scope.list.mode == 'no')                   
                return 'Ответ неверный';
        }        
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="studyCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 new">
        <h2>Вопросы:</h2>
        <label>
            <div class="radio" ng-repeat="button in term">
                <input type="radio"  ng-model="data.mode" value={{button}}/>  {{button}}<br>                
            </div>          
        </label>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <ng-include src="add()"></ng-include>
    </div>
    {{result()}}
```

функция add() при вызове не отображает результат своей работы - подключение выбранной html-страницы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас html не валидный, value должен иметь вид `value="{{button}}"`.
Современные браузеры умные, и они способны приводить html к валидному виду, поэтому в данном случае слэш захватится к value, так как там нет пробелов.

И собственное что бы можно было выбрать установить один вариант, а не все radio button должны иметь одинаковые тэги `name`, например `name="templateSrc"`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь - все заработало!!!

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за полезный комментарий!